# JPA for Oracle Types

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jdbc, user-defined-types

Now that JPA has [stored procedure support](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Advanced_Topics#Stored_Procedures), and my team is upgrading to a newer JavaEE server and specification, we are looking into upgrading an application that uses raw JDBC queries to use JPA instead.

A lot of our Java objects represent Oracle Types in the database.  These types may be `OBJECT`, `VARRAY`, or `TABLE` types.  In JDBC, most of these are handled by [using `SQLData` and a custom type map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqlcustommapping.html).  We are currently handling `TABLE` types directly in the code.

Is there any JPA way of handling these user defined types?

Note: I'm already aware of Hibernate's [`UserType`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/usertype/UserType.html) interface which seems to work similarly to `SQLData`, but I'd prefer to stick with generic JPA if possible as we may go with a different provider.

Comment: In eclipse link exists [@struct](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_struct.htm) but it isn't jpa standard.

Comment: Did you ever got an answer?